# Can Nondet Rabin Tree automaton be determinized?

Tags: reference-request, nondeterminism, tree-automata

In other words, are they equally powerful?

(for *word* automata the answer is "yes"; this question is about *tree* automata).

(i am talking about tree automata that work on $in$finite trees)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, nondeterministic Rabin automata are more expressive than deterministic ones.

As an example, consider the language of $\{a,b\}$-labeled binary trees that contain at least one $b$.

It's easy to construct a two-state Büchi tree automaton for this language (and hence a Rabin automaton), but there is no deterministic equivalent.

You can [look at Lemma 6.1 here, for a start.](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/luke.ong/personal/publications/ALG14-15.pdf)